# Open text file in php and put in database

Tags: php, file, text

I created a simple code to open txt file and put values in mysql database. When I upload the file I have error massage:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(files/szoki.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\betolto\index.php on line
>   60
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\phpF08E.tmp' to 'files/szoki.txt' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\betolto\index.php on line 60
>
> Warning: fopen(files/szoki.txt): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\betolto\index.php on line 61 Unable to
>   open file!

I'm using XAMPP to run this code

What is the problem?

my code is:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['read'])){

    $link=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','szokiadatbazis') or die('could not connect to database'.mysql_error());
    $terminated=$_POST['deli'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['file1']['type'];
    $allow_type=array('text/plain');
    $fieldall="";
    if(in_array($file_type,$allow_type)){

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],"files/".$_FILES['file1']['name']);
      $file=fopen("files/".$_FILES['file1']['name'],"r") or die ("Unable to open file!");
      $tru="truncate table upload_test";
      mysqli_query($link,$tru) or die(mysql_error());
      while(!feof($file)){
      $line = fgets($file);

      $values=str_replace($terminated,"','",$line);
      $sql="insert into upload_test values('$values')";
      mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    }
    fclose($file);//close the file after read
    unlink("files/".$_FILES['file1']['name']);

    }else{
        echo "Please select only text file(.txt file is recomended)!";  

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: smells like permissions to me, and/or something in your unknown form.

Comment: does the folder `files` exist?

Comment: try this insecure fix chmod 0777 -R files/

Comment: I have files folder in C:\xampp\tmp folder

Comment: but when you do move_uploaded_file are relative to "dir(\__ file\__)" path

Comment: just to explain. you are moving to C:\xampp\htdocs\betolto\files and it seem to do not exists or you have to changes its permissions.

Comment: I'm young junior developer :) can you write me a code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open a cmd and type

`mkdir C:\xampp\htdocs\betolto\files
 attrib -r -a -s -h C:\xampp\htdocs\betolto\files\`

if on unix , open a terminal and type:

`mkdir 0755 path_to_http_dir/betolto/files`

as natural for `move_uploaded_file` will pick up  `$_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']` from your **php's tmp dir**

As you unlink the file at the end,  we can simplify the process  by using `sys_get_temp_dir`

but I forgot that tmp_name already contain the full path.

so this line `sys_get_temp_dir() . '/'`  will not be necessary

This way

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['read'])){

        $link=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','szokiadatbazis') or die('could not connect to database'.mysql_error());
        $terminated=$_POST['deli'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['file1']['type'];
        $allow_type=array('text/plain');
        $fieldall="";
        if(in_array($file_type,$allow_type)){

          $file = fopen($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],"r") or die ("Unable to open file!");

          $tru = "truncate table upload_test";
          mysqli_query($link,$tru) or die(mysql_error());

          while(!feof($file)){

             $line = fgets($file);
             $values=str_replace($terminated,"','",$line);
             $sql="insert into upload_test values('$values')";
             mysqli_query($link,$sql);
         }

         fclose($file);//close the file after read

         } else {

            echo "Please select only text file(.txt file is recomended)!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify correctly where to put uploaded file.

```
"files/".$_FILES['file1']['name']
```

probably is not right location.
you can choose relative or absolute path to save your file.
i would suggest you use absolute path and use something like this:

```
$filesPath = dirname(__DIR__);
```

To find where it points to, echo $filesPath and adjust it to point to correct folder, where you want files to be saved..

for example:
if you run your script from c:\xampp\www\project\script.php

```
$filesPath = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "tmp";
```

would point to your c:\xampp\tmp

But better **check correct locations** by printing the variable!

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory